# Android apk Can not build with react-native-image-picker

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

This is the error while building apk react native 0.51

```
  :app:processDebugResources FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > Error: A library uses the same package as this project: com.imagepicker

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 4 mins 51.11 secs
    Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
    Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
    set up your Android development environment:
    https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

[here image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9sX9.png)